# No module named 'backend' [pytest coverage]

Tags: python, pytest-cov

I have a structure like this:

```
myProj
 --backend
   --app.py
 --tests
   --test_app.py
```

When i run the command:

```
pytest -v --cov=.tests/test_app
```

I get:

```
    tests/test_app.py:1: in <module>
    from backend.app import soma
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'
```

Why can't import the library?

When the structure like this:

```
myProj
  --app.py
  --test_app.py
```

Perform correctly.

How can i run coverage in my project with the first showed structure ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `backend` is not a package.

To make it work as a package you should create an empty file named `__init__.py` inside the `backend` folder, so it will work as expected.

To read more about how packages work in Python, [check the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages).

Comment: Yeah! Thank you very much! But, don't work 100%, now i get: `tests/test_app.py ... [100%] Coverage.py warning: Module tests/test_app was never imported. (module-not-imported) Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected) WARNING: Failed to generate report: No data to report. ` More anything tip?

Comment: You should understand whats wrong with the test package you're using. I'm not a heavy user of pytest documentation but I don't see a parameter named `--cov` in the documentation to simulate your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the code structure and making a folder as a module so that it can be imported.

To make any folder work as module, we need to keep __init__.py file(empty or with some data to initialise) inside it. And while importing it make sure it's accessible from that file. i.e. either it is in the same directory or in the exported PYTHONPATH.

Consider following structure:

-- backend:

- __init__.py
- app.py

-- tests:

- __init__.py
- main.py

Here backend and tests are the directories and if you want to import something in main.py file from the app.py file it will go like following:

```
from ..backend.app import soma
```

Note the extra **..** before backend module in above import line that helps the Python interpreter to find the soma from backend/app.py file.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you very much! But, don't work 100%, now i get:


`tests/test_app.py ... [100%]
Coverage.py warning: Module tests/test_app was never imported. (module-not-imported)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
WARNING: Failed to generate report: No data to report.`

Comment: More anything tip?

Comment: I think this is a separate issue and not related to the import of module. As per the logs it seems that code is running but not using the **test_app**. To solve that you need to update the code here. I would recommend to create another question with all the details of your code.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @DiegoQueiroz and @HNMN3, you should make sure your directory as python package.

Add `__init__.py` file inside **backend** and **tests** directory.

Then, you need to mention `module` name in your command.

Given your project structure, you can input this command:

```py
pytest -v --cov=backend.app tests/test_app
```